# Check current user group membership

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to check current user group membership and run the script based on that. This script runs. However, it requires RSAT Active Directory tools to run.

I would like to run this script as a GPO. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
###########################################################################################
# Check AD group Membership
###########################################################################################

$user = "$env:UserName"
$groups = 'FM-TMASQLUserAccess'

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -server **servernamehere** -Identity $group - 
    Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    If ($members -contains $user) {
        Write-Output "$user is a member of $group"
    }
    Else {
        Write-Output  "$user is not a member of $group"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the *current* logged in user, specifically, you don't need to explicitly query AD - the users security token already contains all the group memberships resolved at logon, so you can do:

```
$groupName = 'FM-TMASQLUserAccess'

# Fetch identity information about current user
$currentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()

# Grab group SIDs from the users token
$groupTokenSIDs = $currentUser.Groups

# Translate the SID references to account/group names
$Groups = $groupTokenSIDs |Where-Object { $_.AccountDomainSid } |ForEach-Object { $_.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) }

# Test if list contains target group
if($Groups |Where-Object { $_.Value -like "*\$groupName" }){
  "$env:USERNAME is a member of $groupName"
}
```

Comment: Does this only return domain groups? How can I find local groups?

Comment: @lit It returns both local groups, domain groups, and global identifiers/labels - anything already in the users access token. Variable naming was slightly misleading, I've updated the code.

Comment: When I run this, the `$Groups` variable contains only names prefixed with the AD domain; `EAST\ `. There is no `Administrators` or `Users` group.

Comment: IMO this code should say `$_.Value` in the `Where-Object` filter that translates the SIDs (rather than `$_.AccountDomainSid`).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That's deliberate. OP is interested in a non-builtin **AD** group, I'm filtering out WKSIDs (like `BUILTIN\Users`) - in an attempt to narrow the list without having to resolve the actual domain SID :)

Comment: As I said, just my opinion (regardless of OP intent, I find it more useful to include all groups, for various reasons).

Comment: Thank you for all your help !!

Comment: I tied that code and it didn't return anything. Am I missing something?